# Array reduce: How to handle empty array from previous filter?

Tags: javascript

I have an array which gets filtered and which possibly results in the new array being empty. Afterwards I have a reducer function on it, which then fails on an empty array:

*Uncaught TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value*

How can i break before the reduce if the filter returns an empty array?

Code

```js
var array = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

var sum = array
  .filter((a) => a < 5)
  .reduce((a, b) => a + b)

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Reduce_of_empty_array_with_no_initial_value (if you're getting an error and don't know how to fix it, just google the error message)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Provide an initial value as a second parameter to `reduce`. In this case, since it's a sum, the appropriate value is presumably `0`:

```js
var array = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

var sum = array
  .filter((a) => a < 5)
  .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
// ----------------------^^^

console.log(sum);
```

Without an initial value or at least one entry, `reduce` can't do its job, it has nothing to return. When it has just one entry and no initial value, it returns the first entry (without ever calling the callback). But without even one entry...

Answer (score 5):

The error you got should hint at the solution.

> *Uncaught TypeError: Reduce of empty array **with no initial value***

Reduce takes a second parameter, the initial value to reduce onto.

```
.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just reduce:

```
 array.reduce((res, el) => res + el * (el < 5), 0)
```